# Организация файловой структуры в веб-приложении

Tags: веб-программирование, структуры-данных, highload, big-data

Допустим в веб-приложении, есть такая сущность "файл", данная сущность делится на два типа: "media" и "simple". Углубимся в тип "media". В media входят такие разновидности: изображения, видео и аудио. Рассмотрим "изображения", у такой разновидности есть конфиг, который включает в себя допустимые форматы, степень сжатия, количество и размеры превью, путь к директории где хранятся все файлы такой разновидности.

У такой структуры есть свои плюсы и минусы. Очевидным **плюсом** является то, что для того чтобы задать для конкретного поля формы, куда должна сохраняться картинка, какой у нее будет формат, размер и тд. - достаточно создать для нее свой тип со своим конфигом, и файлы будут ложиться так как нам надо и куда мы скажем. Так же, если например файлы переехали в другой каталог или на другой сервер, то мы просто редактируем конфиг типа данной разновидности media, указав там новый адрес. Так же, если вдруг нам понадобились превью новых размеров например для новых страниц сайта, то мы просто в конфиге прописываем новый вид превью со своими параметрами, запускаем процедуру перегенерации превью и она нам нарежет новые превью из оригиналов. Самый **жирный минус** такой структуры заключается в том, что когда мы хотим достать файл, то мы сначала получаем id ресурса, здесь же будет сложный запрос с join'oм, где по id ресурса нужно достать файлы и id типа, и тут же вытаскивать тип. Так-то получаем в основном запросе два join'a. Вот это мне и не очень нравится.

Есть ли у вас идеи как-то упростить это все, при этом не урезав гибкость? (варианты с кэшированием пока не рассматриваю, т.к. для начала хочу упростить все это без использования кэша).

Comment: Вы не рассматриваете облачное кластерное хранилище для медиа-файлов? Swift, Ceph, S3? Они безразмерны, они прекрасно масштабируются?

Comment: Нет, пока все в рамках вопроса